# sql how to get consecutive appearance of value

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor

suppose I have a column 'value', which can appear multiple times in a table with another column 'result' which can be either 1 or 0. I would like to search for consecutive 1s (ie result = 1) until the count reaches 4, then I can select value. given the result sets below:

-result set a)

```
value Result
 ----- ------         
 A      1
 A      1
 A      1
 A      0
```

-result set b)

```
value Result
 ----- ------         
 A      1
 A      1
 A      1
 A      1
```

result set b meets the condition and therefore value A is selected. How do I go about this ? Thanks.

Comment: "consecutive" as ordered by what? There is no default ordering of rows in a table.

Comment: consecutive ordered by a 'date'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the query: (usually this query is to detect double record in a table, but probably meet your demand).

```
select value, result, count(value) as [Result Sum]
from @temp
where result = 1
group by value, result
having count(value) >3
```

This is the Result

```
value result      Result Sum
----- ----------- -----------
A     1           4
```

**UPDATED:**

This is the data example in my temporary table (@temp)

```
value result
----- -----------
A     1
A     1
A     1
A     0
A     1
D     1
D     1
D     1
D     1
B     1
B     1
C     1
C     1
C     1
C     1
```

From The example data C and D are the valid values

```
Declare @temp2 table
(
 value nvarchar(5)
)
declare @value nvarchar(5), @result int, @total int, @flag bit, @tempValue nvarchar(5)
DECLARE myCursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT value, result 
FROM @temp

set @flag = 1
set @tempValue = ''
OPEN myCursor;
FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor into @value, @result;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
     --logic here

          if (@tempValue <> @value and @result = 1) or @flag = 1
            begin
                set @tempValue = @value
                set @total = 1
                set @flag = 0
            end
          else --@tempvalue = @value 
            begin
                if @result = 1 
                    set @total = @total + 1
                else --@result = 0
                    set @flag = 1

                if @total >3 --valid value has reached 4 consecutive result =1
                    begin
                        set @flag = 1
                        insert into @temp2 values (@value)
                    end
            end


     FETCH NEXT FROM myCursor into @value, @result;

   END;
CLOSE myCursor;
DEALLOCATE myCursor;

select * from @temp2
```

This is the Result of the loop (table @temp2)

```
value
-----
D
C

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Hi Cyan, I had written a  similar query, the problem is that It only needs to select A if result = 1 appears CONSECUTIVELY 4 times, not just getting a count greater than 4

Comment: oops sorry about that. I think you need a loop process to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in a select statement.  You can find groups of items in a row by using `row_number()` assuming you have an `id`.  SQL tables are inherently unordered, so you need an `id` or creation date or something to specify the ordering.  Here is the SQL:

```
select value
from (select t,
             (row_number() over (partition by value order by id) -
              row_number() over (partition by value, results order by id)
             ) as grp
      from table t
     ) t
group by value, result, grp
having count(*) > 3 and result = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I dont understand the 'select t' part , since you are fetching from 'table t' ...also want to order by a date so each row has a date row associated with it

Comment: @AndrisMudiayi . . .  Do you have an `id` (of some sort) in your data?